# Bootstrap nav row resizes smoothly, but active or highlighted links are only partially highlighted

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

On smaller screen, one of the links in this nav (nav-pills, nav-justified) takes up two lines, which makes the "box" size bigger for the other links in the nav as well. That's great, except that active or highlighted links only highlight part of the box, as shown in the image below. It doesn't look so good, yeah?

[image of nav row](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/816x381q90/539/o7RIh4.jpg)

How can I make the active or highlighted part fill up the whole box?
Also, how can I vertically center the link within the box?

Here's the relevant html:

```
<nav> 
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li><a href="#">Atmosphere</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Food</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drink</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Access &amp; Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Coupons</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reservation</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And css:

```
header, section, footer, aside, nav, main, article, figure {display: block;}

nav > ul > li {
    border: 4px #abcabc;
    border-style: double;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
    color: #c30200;
    font-family: Garamond, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Could you post what code you have tried thus far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Normally highlighted part fill up the whole box. If its not means post your code,

For vertically center you need to apply `text-center`

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/8HqzpEdkyy)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Hmm, text-center isn't working for me. Maybe the first problem needs to be solved first.